# What's the difference between `_bookdown.yml`, `_output.yml` and yaml header of the first document?

Tags: r, bookdown

When authoring a document with [bookdown](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/), I am aware of four options to put configuration options:

- `_bookdown.yml`
- `_output.yml`
- the yaml header of the first `.Rmd` document
- arguments passed to the `bookdown::render_book()` function.

**Now my question:**

- Which options **can** go where, i.e. can I use all files interchangeably?
- Which options **should** go where, i.e. what is good practice to put the configuration options?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*so far I know...hope others can complete this*

First have a look at this high level explanation [R markdown](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/bookdown-project.html#output.yml)
next use the hyperlinks provided below which all point to the documentation details

#### YAML header of the first *.Rmd file

- can contain additional pandoc parameters as described [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/usage.html).
- It must contain the following line: **site: bookdown::bookdown_site**
- may contain multiple output formats specified by

  ```
  output: 
    bookdown::gitbook:
    bookdown::pdf_book:
    bookdown::epub_book:
  ```

... but these can also be in the _output.yml as described [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/output-formats.html) all formats should be at the top level, instead of under an output field.

[Example](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/html.html#gitbook-style)

#### _bookdown.yml

All [_bookdown.yml](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/configuration.html) parameters used for generating the book and save the results.

**Example**

```
    book_filename: "_book_example"
    repo: https://github.com/<user>/<repo>/ 
    before_chapter_script: ["script1.R"]
    after_chapter_script:  ["script2.R"]
    output_dir: "_book"
    clean: ["deleteme.Rmd"]
    rmd_files: ["index.Rmd", "02-literature.Rmd", "01-intro.Rmd"]
    delete_merged_file: true
    language:
      label: 
        fig: "FIGURE " 
        tab: "TABLE " 
      ui:
        edit: "Edit"
        chapter_name: "Chapter "
    rmd_subdir: ["content/"]
```